# My program won't work. Can't find the solution on my own

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i'm about to make one of my first graphical programs and I got stuck. I can't get this to work, it's no errors so it's looks right when i run it on eclipse but a new window don't open like it supposed to do. It's just a little part of the whole program.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Inlupp2 extends JFrame{
    JTextField ordFält = new JTextField();
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea();

    Inlupp2() {
        super("Inlupp2");

        JPanel norr = new JPanel();
        add(norr, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Ny: ");
        norr.add(lab);
        norr.add(ordFält);

        JButton searchKnapp = new JButton("Search");
        norr.add(searchKnapp);
        searchKnapp.addActionListener(new SearchLyss());

        JButton hideKnapp = new JButton("Hide place");
        norr.add(hideKnapp);
        hideKnapp.addActionListener(new HideLyss());

        JButton deleteKnapp = new JButton("Delete places");
        norr.add(deleteKnapp);
        deleteKnapp.addActionListener(new deleteKnapp());

        JButton locationKnapp = new JButton("What is here?");
        norr.add(locationKnapp);
        locationKnapp.addActionListener(new locationKnapp());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    class locationKnapp implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){

        }
    }

    class deleteKnapp implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){

        }
    }
    class HideLyss implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){

        }
    }

    class SearchLyss implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {

        }
    }

        public static void String(String[] args) {
            new Inlupp2();
        }

}
```

Comment: I know that this: import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; isn't needed right now.

Comment: I'm very confused about your code and your question as it is long on unexplained code and short on descriptive exposition. Can you tell us more about what this program is supposed to do, what it should be doing but is not doing, what it shouldn't be doing but is doing? A couple of paragraphs of explanation can greatly help us in our efforts to help you. Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: `public static void String(String[] args) {` - what?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is bad formulated, i'm new at stackowerflow so i will definitely look in the "help center" and "how to as good questions". 
When i run the program it supposed to pop up a new window with buttons, text and so on like it's written in the code but it don't. But the thing that make me confused is that I don't get any errors by the compiler so I cant figur out what's wrong about the code.

Comment: Your confusion may be that you equate compilable code with "good" code, and that's not a valid equation. If code compiles, then all you can say is that it is free of compilation errors, but this tells you nothing about logic errors. In the future, please try to post a more descriptive question title, one that summarize your actual problem similar to a newspaper article headline. Doing this will help you get better help. Also add more explanation to your question, rather than brief vague explanation and a large unexplained code dump. Again doing this will help get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at the point where you wrote:

```
public static void String(String[] args) {
        new Inlupp2();
    }
```

you should probably write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Inlupp2();
    }
```

Comment: Oh, of course it is... I'm very new to java and programming generally. I've sat like 2 hours and looked in examples and so on to figured out the problem. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, nobody started from the top ;)

Answer (score 0):

You accidently modified main method (Which is a starting/entry point) to name it as String.

So instead of

```
public static void String(String[] args) {
```

Change it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Oh, of course it is... I'm very new to java and programming generally. I've sat like 2 hours and looked in examples and so on to figured out the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @downvoter may i know why its downvoted for right answer please?

Comment: @LinusJohnsson if you feel this answer has helped, then you could tick on button just below vote count so it could help others in future.